# many extra .aut files under the directory of tomcat's webapps after deploying war package

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

My web applciation uses maven to generate war package and tomcat as server.But sometiemrs I find that,after deploying the war package into webapps,there are many extra .aut files along with useful files of my project,just like this:
[image]

I really don't know why,can anybody give some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the automaton.jar is extracted to the project directory
[image]